# How do I index into a point cloud's points

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I was working on a project and stumbled upon an issue with the indexing in three dimensions.

How do I index into the z value of a point?

Comment: What do you mean by *depth*? In PCL point clouds are most commonly stored in an un-ordered fashion? The Point itself holds your Cartesian information.

Comment: @Ben By depth I mean the z coordinate.  I am asking whether or not one can use cloud->points[i] to get a z value.

Comment: I have added an answer, you should format your question correctly and add some more detail about what you wanted. Then i will upvote and retract my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCL most commonly stores its point cloud information in an un-ordered form. The point itself carries the information you might need.

For example the type `PointXYZ` has the following structure:

```
pcl::PointXYZ::PointXYZ (   
    float   _x,
    float   _y,
    float   _z 
)
```

Find out more about the point types [here.](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/structpcl_1_1_point_x_y_z.html#a9e3c47eb692f08aca31885bb33942514)

So in  order to get the z information, you would do the following:

```
cloud->points[i]._z; // Depth information from a point in your point cloud.
```